# Visual basic 2008 - Do...While until infinite loop when shuffling 52 card deck

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, boolean, infinite-loop, do-while

I'm starting to make a Hearts game in VB2008. Currently I'm stuck with the dealing:

```
 For q = 0 To 51
        Do
            Randomize()
            dealrand = Int(Rnd() * 51)
            cards(q).Image = pics(dealrand)
        Loop Until dealused(dealrand) = False
        dealused(dealrand) = True
    Next
```

What I'm trying to do is check if the card has been used and generate a different card, so nobody would get the same card.

When I press the button, the program crashes. I think it's an infinite loop, because when I changed `cards(q).Image = pics(dealrand)` to `cards(q).hide`, it hid one card and crashed.

P.S:

- All of the "dealused" variables are set to False when created.
- "pics" is an image array (as in image files), but I don't think that's the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem may be that you've missed that [`Rnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) returns a value between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive), meaning when cast to integer, it will never return the upper bound value. So you will need to extend the upper bound to 52 to ensure that index #51 is eventually 'found'.

You can also save some work by only assigning the `q`th card after the next empty index is found, and I believe seeding `Randomize` just once will suffice:

```
    Dim q As Integer
    Dim dealrand As Integer
    Dim dealused = Enumerable.Range(0, 52).Select(Function(x) False).ToArray
    Randomize()
    For q = 0 To 51
        Do
            dealrand = Int(Rnd() * 52)
        Loop Until dealused(dealrand) = False
        cards(q).Image = pics(dealrand)
        dealused(dealrand) = True
    Next
```

**Edit**

I believe the card shuffling routine can be done in a single loop, without the hit-or-miss approach of trying to find an unused card, by projecting all 52 cards available (0..51) and then eliminating them once a random card is pulled from the deck. It exploits the fact that `List` also has a index operator.

```
    Dim dealrand As Integer
    Dim cardsAvailable = Enumerable.Range(0, 52).ToList()
    Dim q As Integer = 0
    Randomize()
    While (cardsAvailable.Any())
        dealrand = Int(Rnd() * cardsAvailable.Count)
        cards(q).Image = pics(cardsAvailable(dealrand))
        cardsAvailable.RemoveAt(dealrand)
        q = q + 1
    End While
```